# How to create a new column based on values from rows that match values in other columns?

Tags: r, string, match

Suppose I have a data frame with a few categorical variables and some columns that are string values.  I would like to create a new column that, for each row, pastes string values from other rows if certain values in the categorical columns match (or don't match).  Here is a toy example.

```
toy <- data.frame("id" = c(1,2,3,2), "year" = c(2000,2000,2004,2004), "words" = c("a b", "c d", "e b", "c d"))
```

I would like to create a variable `word_pool` that is pasted from other rows' `words` column if two criteria are met:  the row's `id` value is different from the current row's id value and the row's `year` value is less than the current row's year value.

What should result is

```
id year words word_pool
1 2000    a b
2 2000    c d
3 2004    e b   a b c d
2 2004    c d       a b
```

The first two rows will be blank for the new column since there isn't a year less than 2000 in the toy example.  The last row will only have "a b" as the value in the new column since its `id` is repeated.

I've tried various `apply` and `group_by` approaches but none seem to fit the bill exactly.  Would appreciate any and all ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used `sqldf` and `plyr` packages to achieve the solution. Though I wouldn't call this an elegant solution it works. Hope to see a more efficient solution from others.

```
library(sqldf)

toy <- data.frame("id" = c(1,2,3,2), 
                   "year" = c(2000,2000,2004,2004), 
                   "words" = c("a b", "c d", "e b", "c d"))

toy

#  id year words
#1  1 2000   a b
#2  2 2000   c d
#3  3 2004   e b
#4  2 2004   c d

df <- sqldf('SELECT t1.*,t2.words AS word_pool FROM toy t1 LEFT JOIN toy t2 
       ON t1.year > t2.year AND
       t1.words <> t2.words')

df
#  id year words word_pool
#1  1 2000   a b      <NA>
#2  2 2000   c d      <NA>
#3  3 2004   e b       a b
#4  3 2004   e b       c d
#5  2 2004   c d       a b

result <- plyr::ddply(df,c("id","year","words"), 
                      function(dfx)paste(dfx$word_pool, 
                                         collapse = " "))

result
#  id year words      V1
#1  1 2000   a b      NA
#2  2 2000   c d      NA
#3  2 2004   c d     a b
#4  3 2004   e b a b c d
```

Comment: This works, and I'm also interested to see if others have different solutions.  Do you think this would scale to thousands of rows efficiently?

Comment: sqldf is pretty much efficient. The bottleneck if there ever was could be for the plyr part. However,  I've used similar code for at least a million observations without any problems. So for the order of thousands, you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

With a for and which, this  must write like apply and no use extern libraries

```
        ## Create data
        toy <-
          data.frame(
            "id" = c(1, 2, 3, 2),
            "year" = c(2000, 2000, 2004, 2004),
            "words" = c("a b", "c d", "e b", "c d")
          )

        toy$word_pool <- 0
        for (i in 1:length(toy)) {
          # Recognize index from condition
          condition_index <- which(toy$year[i] > toy$year
                                        & toy$id[i] != toy$id)
          # assign
          if (length(condition_index) == 0){# case no index
            toy$word_pool[i] = ""
          }
          else{# paste with collapse join array
            toy$word_pool[i] = paste(toy$words[condition_index],
                                     collapse = " ", sep = " ")
          }
        }
        toy
        # id year words word_pool
        # 1  2000   a b          
        # 2  2000   c d          
        # 3  2004   e b   a b c d
        # 2  2004   c d       a b
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  Certainly works, but ideally the solution won't use a loop (the actual data I'm working with has thousands of rows).